# Second derivative of a composition in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis

let $A \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and $B \subseteq \mathbb R^k$ be two open sets and $f : A\to \mathbb R^k$ and $g:B\to \mathbb R^m$ be doubly differentiable and $f(A)\subseteq B$ , then obviously $g \circ f : A \to \mathbb R^m$ is well defined and $$D(g\circ f)(x)=Dg(f(x))\circ Df(x)$$
Is the first differential of a composition (by the chain rule). Now this function is differentiable since all of $Df, Dg, f$ are differentiable but i am not sure if i should look at this function as triple composition $$Dg(f(Df(x)))$$ which doesn't look right.

Edit this is what I got from 1 day of thought :D

$f : A \to B, g: B \to \mathbb R^m, A\subseteq \mathbb R^n, B\subseteq \mathbb R^k$

$$
\frac{\partial^2(g\circ f)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x) 
=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{\partial(g\circ f)}{\partial x_j}(x)\right) =\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\nabla (g\circ f)(x)e_j \right) \\=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\nabla g(f(x))\nabla f(x)e_j) \right)
=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\nabla g(f(x)) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x) \right)\\ 
=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\sum_{p=1}^k  \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_p}(f(x))\frac{\partial f_p}{\partial x_j}(x)\right)
=\sum_{p=1}^k\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_p}(f(x))\frac{\partial f_p}{\partial x_j}(x) \right)\\
=\sum_{p=1}^k\left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_p}(f(x)) \right)\frac{\partial f_p}{\partial x_j}(x)+\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_p}(f(x)) \frac{\partial^2f_p}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x) \right]\\
= \sum_{p=1}^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_p}(f(x)) \right)\frac{\partial f_p}{\partial x_j}(x)+ \sum_{p=1}^k \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_p}(f(x)) \frac{\partial^2f_p}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x)\\
=\sum_{p=1}^k\sum_{l=1}^k\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x_l\partial x_p}(f(x))\frac{\partial f_l}{\partial x_i}(x)\frac{\partial f_p}{\partial x_j}(x)+\sum_{p=1}^k \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_p}(f(x)) \frac{\partial^2f_p}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x)
$$

Also from this we get 
$$D^2(g\circ f)(x)(h,k)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial^2(g\circ f)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x) h_ik_j\\
=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{p=1}^k\sum_{l=1}^k\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x_l\partial x_p}(f(x))\frac{\partial f_l}{\partial x_i}(x)\frac{\partial f_p}{\partial x_j}(x)+\sum_{p=1}^k \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_p}(f(x)) \frac{\partial^2f_p}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x) \right)h_ik_j\\
=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{p=1}^k\sum_{l=1}^k\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x_l\partial x_p}(f(x))\frac{\partial f_l}{\partial x_i}(x)h_i\frac{\partial f_p}{\partial x_j}(x)k_j\right)\\+ \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{p=1}^k \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_p}(f(x)) \frac{\partial^2f_p}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x)h_ik_j \right)\\
=\sum_{p=1}^k\sum_{l=1}^k\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x_l\partial x_p}(f(x))\left(\sum_{l=1}^n\frac{\partial f_l}{\partial x_i}(x)h_i\right)\left(\sum_{p=1}^n\frac{\partial f_p}{\partial x_j}(x)k_j \right)\\
+\sum_{p=1}^k \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_p}(f(x))\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial^2f_p}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x)h_ik_j\right)\\
=\sum_{p=1}^k\sum_{l=1}^k\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x_l\partial x_p}(f(x))(Df_l(x)h)(Df_p(x)k)\\+\sum_{p=1}^k \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_p}(f(x))D^2f_p(x)(h,k)\\
=\sum_{p=1}^k\sum_{l=1}^k\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x_l\partial x_p}(f(x))(Df(x)h)_l(Df(x)k)_p\\+\sum_{p=1}^k \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_p}(f(x))\left(D^2f(x)(h,k)\right)_p\\=D^2g(f(x))(Df(x)h,Dg(x)k)+Dg(f(x))(D^2f(x)(h,k))
$$

That is  we get 
$$D^2(g\circ f)(x)(h,k)=D^2g(f(x))(Df(x)h,Dg(x)k)+Dg(f(x))(D^2f(x)(h,k))$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The expression $Dg(f(x))$ denote the derivative of the function $g$ at the point $f(x)$, which in turn is a (linear) function from $\mathbb R^k$ to $\mathbb R^m$. 
Also, observe that $Dg(f(x))$ is the evaluation of the function $Dg : \mathbb R^k \to \mathcal{L}
(\mathbb R^k,\mathbb R^m)$ at $f(x)$, where $\mathcal{L}
(\mathbb R^k,\mathbb R^m)$ is the space of all the linear maps from $\mathbb R^k$ to $\mathbb R^m$.

And, for your specific question, since $D(g\circ f)(x)$ is a linear function, its derivative is itself. That is,
$$D\big(\color{red}{D(g\circ f)(x)}\big)(a) = \color{red}{D(g\circ f)(x)}$$
at any point $a\in\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: so is the answer then $D^2g(f(x))(Df(x))\circ D^2f(x)$

Comment: Chech the new version of my answer.

Comment: Is there perhaps a D missing somewhere? or a ^2

Comment: Everything is fine as written.

Comment: oh thank you i am dumb